# Teams Graph API - how to cancel an Invited participant

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am inviting parties into a call using

```
await graphClient.Communications.Calls["{call-id}"].Participants
    .Invite(participants,clientContext)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

as shown here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

This works fine, and I am able to detect responses from the invited party : Accept, Decline and Timeout via the callbacks.

However what I would like to do is to be able to cancel the invitation before the callee picks it up.

I assumed that the Delete primitive would allow me to do this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

but at this point in the sequence, I do not have a participant ID for the invited party because it is not yet in the call.

So. My question is, how can I cancel an invitation after it has been issued ?

Thanks

Comment: There doesn't seems to be any graph API available to cancel an Invited participant.
Could you please raise an user voice here:

 https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately that link does not work for me (404)

Comment: Use this link for uservoice: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer from comment section for more visibility.

There doesn't seems to be any graph API available to cancel an Invited participant.

Could you please raise an user voice here:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Comment: I have added feedback, thanks.  Am I likely to get a response to it do you know.  It has come to a screeching halt.